# Draw a chart for values against time chunks

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this. I want to draw a chart as X:Time and Y:Amount. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

EDIT:

As per @doubleunary's comment, here is an editable sheet with what I exactly want. If I try to explain the use case to make it easy to understand, let's say I get paid for services I offer for different time ranges. Now I want to draw a chart to show the real daily income I got. Hope it's clear.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjG5zaz59ryCndvoutgLXrHQq2YF7FKjdJRR316UyrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is unclear whether you want a simple chart that shows either the start date or the end date in the X axis, or a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) that uses the number of days in each start-end period as bucket size. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data and explain what the resulting chart should look like.

Comment: Makes sense. I updated the question with an editable sheet. Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sum(filter())` pattern, like this:

`=sequence( max(A3:B9) - min(A3:B9) + 1, 1, min(A3:B9) )`

`=iferror( 1 / sum( filter(E$3:E$9, A$3:A$9 <= A11, A11 <= B$3:B$9) ) ^ -1 )`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjG5zaz59ryCndvoutgLXrHQq2YF7FKjdJRR316UyrE/edit#gid=1924811707) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

The `iferror(1/()^-1)` pattern ensures that cells where there is no result remain blank.